# Relationship between differential geometry and quantum computation?

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, lie-groups, lie-algebras, quantum-computation

I have just started reading about quantum computation (Quantum Computation and Quantum Information, Nielsen and Chuang).

In parallel, I have to study differential geometry for a final exam. After the standard part of it, where you must cover the basic topics, the professor lets you present a related topic (it's optional). I was wondering if I can present some connection between differential geometry and quantum computation. The most promising thing I found is a couple of articles by Howard Brandt (see for example [this one](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11128-011-0290-6).) about Riemmanian geometry.

Can anyone give me more recommendations? The two non obligatory constraints are the following:

1. I'm a beginner at quantum computation.
2. If the relationship has anything to do with Frobenius theorem, much better. I also like Lie algebra.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Perhaps if you add 'Lie Algebras' as a tag more people will see your question and someone may answer

Comment: Classical mechanics take place on a symplectic manifold, which is a differentiable manifold equipped with a nondegenerate 2-form. There is some big theory of what it means to "quantise" this situation, to get to a corresponding quantum mechanical theory. But perhaps this is too in-depth (or equally well, too vague!). As a completely different idea, have you looked at topological quantum error correction?